# Multiple users on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8, ios9

I've been brainstorming an idea to create an app that would allow an individual to use the fingerprint ID hardware to log into any enabled device, allowing access to that individuals set of apps that have been linked to their fingerprint profile.

For example, I could use my wife's phone by using my fingerprint to unlock her phone, but instead of seeing her apps I would see my apps on her phone.  My thought is that a persons fingerprint would access their personal profile in the cloud though an app that could be downloaded to a device. My cloud profile would have the apps I want to access from anywhere and my fingerprint (or other method) would give me access to those apps, on any device that had the gateway app installed on it.

Is this idea even possible on iOS without operating system support?

Comment: Moreover this is not an app idea. Why would you ask something that is not meant to do!!!!

Comment: by the way, iOS is itself an operating system. There isn't anything like iOS with or without operating system. It jsut doesnt make sense.

Comment: i think you can use this for Android. not for iOS

Comment: @Mr.T yeah that part I know :) My question is if this kind of functionality is possible with just a stand-alone app, or if an API from the operating system would be needed.

Comment: @sandy dude, there is no such API.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Nope.

iOS itself (along with the device) manages access to Touch ID, and the support provided for third party apps is purely binary — that is, [your app can prompt for Touch ID authentication](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LocalAuthentication_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014520), and the system tells you only whether authentication was successful. You don't get to know which of the enrolled fingers was used to authenticate.

Beyond that, third-party apps don't get to control the set of other apps visible to the user on the home screen, app data and documents, system settings like email and iMessage logins, etc. OS-level multiuser support isn't something you can do from an App Store app, and probably not through other means, either.

Answer (score 3):

No man, not possible, sorry. You are asking way deep things to do in iOS, that you are simply not allowed to.

Comment: Please provide more content than this. References, in particular would be useful here.